# Math.cos giving bad results for large values

Tags: java

I've seen a few answers to this but I still haven't found one that works for me.  When I try this :

```
return Math.cos(270.* Math.PI/180);
```

i get

```
-1.8369701987210297E-16
```

while: -

```
Math.cos(Math.toRadians(270.) // gives:-1.8369701987210297E-16
```

I was expecting this to give 0.

Comment: It's because of floating-point arguments.

Answer (score 6):

The number `-1.8369701987210297E-16` is the [scientific representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) of a number that is *extremely* close to zero. It is equivalent to this number:

```
-0.000000000000000018369701987210297
```

Floating point arithmetic is not precise. You should expect small representation errors. In particular it is not possible to represent an [irrational number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrational_number) like pi exactly as a floating point number.

Answer (score 1):

`Math.PI` is an approximation, so you will get an approximate value of `zero`.

Try using a margin of error `epsilon` with a value approximate `1E-16`.
So if a cos result is inferior to epsilon that means it is null.

You can also develop your own modified `cos` function.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another example of the not perfect precision in case of floating point numbers. You converting it and it results in a not perfect 0 value. It is pretty close to zero however.

It has nothing to do with large values. In case of float numbers, always expect minor differences.